# Restarting attached Android process using IDA

Tags: android, stack, ida

I have attached to a process running on an Android phone and I would like to be able to restart the process to step through the initialization code.  The process of interest is a native process (not running with the help of Dalvik).  After attaching I am able to reset the program counter, however I'm not resetting the stack pointer to the correct starting address.

Executing 'cat /proc/proc_id/maps' I'm able to see where the stack is located in memory, and I understand that the loader will populate the stack with command line arguments (argc/argv) and environmental variables.  The question that I have is how do I find the stack address to load into SP when the process first starts?  The file is an .elf file...